# Changing logging Level for Kafka Consumer/Producer/ Streams-Application

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, log4j, slf4j, log-level

I found that Kafka by default prints everything as stderr
I want to change that and i found i have to add an log4j.properties file

I have created one and added properties that atleast should change it for an consumer but everything is still written to stderr

I have the same properties file also in main/ressources just to be sure

[image: Picture of my log4j.properties file]

[image: My pom.xml]

Answer (score 1):

`log4j.properties` is for log4j 1.x, which is what Kafka uses

However, you've defined log4j 2.x as your dependency, which is going to look for a **`log4j2.properties`** file in `src/main/resources`

Comment: So what do i have to change the loggin? rename the properties file or change my dependencie in the pom.xml?

Comment: I'd start with changing your dependencies to remove the `org.apache.logging` ones and try using logback (with a logback.xml file instead). For example https://github.com/OneCricketeer/kafka-streams-jib-example/blob/master/src/main/resources/logback.xml